# Vue js send data by chunks

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asynchronous, async-await

I would like to send the data by chunks
now what i'm sending to the server look like this
for loop - 1, 2, 3
what the server receives: 3,1,2 -> asynchronous.
and i need to send it synchronic so the server will receive as my for loop order: 1, 2, 3
How can i do it ?

```
//52428800
                const chunkSize = 1377628
                let beginUpload = data;
                let component = this;
                let start = 0;
                let startCount = 0;
                let callStoreCouunt = 0;
                
                for (start; start < zipedFile.length; start += chunkSize) {
                    const chunk = zipedFile.slice(start, start + chunkSize + 1)
                    startCount +=1;
                        // debugger
                        // var base64Image = new Buffer( zipedFile ).toString('base64');
                        var base64Image = new Buffer( chunk ).toString('base64');
                        console.log(chunk, startCount);

                    let uploadPackage: documentInterfaces.UploadPackage = {
                        transaction: {
                            documentId: {value: data.documentId.value},
                            transactionId: data.transactionId,
                            fileGuid: data.fileGuid
                        },
                        packageBuffer: base64Image
                    };
                    // debugger

                    


                    component.$store.dispatch('documents/uploadPackage', uploadPackage)
                    .then(({ data, status }: { data: documentInterfaces.ReciveAttachScene , status: number }) => {
                        // debugger
                        if(status !== 200){
                            component.$message({
                                message: data,
                                type: "error"
                            });
                            component.rejectUpload(beginUpload);
                        }
                        else{
                            callStoreCouunt+=1;
                            console.log(chunk, "res" + callStoreCouunt)
                            debugger
                            if(callStoreCouunt === startCount){
        
                                let commitPackage = {
                                    transaction: {
                                        documentId: {value: uploadPackage.transaction.documentId.value},
                                        transactionId: uploadPackage.transaction.transactionId,
                                        fileGuid: uploadPackage.transaction.fileGuid
                                    }
                                };
                              debugger
                                component.commitUpload(commitPackage);
                            }
                        }
                        });
                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot control which chunk of data reaches the server first. If there's a network problem somewhere on its way, it might go around the planet multiple times before it reaches the server.

Even if the 1st chunk was sent `5 ms` earlier than the 2nd one, the 2nd chunk might reach the server earlier.

But there's a few ways you can solve this:

### Method 1:

Wait for the server response before sending the next chunk:

```js
let state = {
  isPaused: false
}
let sentChunks = 0
let totalChunks = getTotalChunksAmount()
let chunkToSend = ...

setInterval(() => {
  if (!isPaused && sentChunks < totalChunks) {
    state.isPaused = true
    send(chunkToSend)
    sentChunks += 1
  }
}, 100)

onServerReachListener(response => {
  if (response === ...) {
    state.isPaused = false
  }
})
```

### Method 2:

If you don't need to process chunks sequentially in real time, you can just wait for all of them to arrive on the server, then sort them before processing:

```js
let chunks = []
onChunkReceived (chunk) {
  if (chunk.isLast) {
    chunks.push(chunk)
    chunks.sort()
    processChunks()  
  }
  else {
    chunks.push(chunk)
  }
}
```

### Method 3:

If you do need to process chunks sequentially in real time, give all the chunks an id property and processing them sequentially, while storing the other ones for later:

```js
let chunksToProcess = []
let lastProcessedChunkId = -1 
 
onChunkReceived (chunk) {
  if (chunk.id === lastProcessedChunkId) { 
    processChunk()
    lastProcessedChunkId += 1
    processStoredChunks()
  }
  else {
    chunksToProcess.push(chunk)
  }
}
```